# Is there a way to not have Lion not launch apps from previous startup?

Tags: macos, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reopen windows when logging back in - NOT](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20651/reopen-windows-when-logging-back-in-not)
>   [How can I keep restore for apps in Lion without having session restore when I log in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22656/how-can-i-keep-restore-for-apps-in-lion-without-having-session-restore-when-i-lo)

I've heard conflicting info on this - seems like a good place for an option on startup. Any ideas? I just want a clean slate and find it annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this in `System Preferences > General`. Look for the "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps" check box and uncheck it.

[image]